# How to make sticky section change colours?

Tags: html, css

I am a beginner and I am trying to make a sticky section change colour similar to this website (https://hydracup.com), where when you scroll it changes colour to the different products that it offers.

So far I have made the sections sticky, however I have no clue on how to make the colour change sections. Any help appreciated thanks.

```
<header>header</header>
<main>
  <div class="sticky">STICKY</div>
</main>
<footer>footer</footer>
```

```
header {
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: blue;
  background-size: cover;
}

main {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 200vh;
  background-color: red;
}

footer {
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: blue;
  background-size: cover;
  position: sticky;
  top: 50%;
}
```

Comment: I believe you have to use Javascript for that. In short, you have to make an event when the scroll position changes and there change the background color on the positions you want.

Comment: You have to add event listener (DOM concept) to that element. When the user scrolls a function is called . 'onscroll' event might work in your case. Refer this docs https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_event.asp